# Rust returns integer when doing usize.clone()?

Tags: for-loop, rust, integer, borrow-checker, ownership

I have the following code that takes `usize` in an enum and I wanted to iterate on that `usize`. When I pass `usize` directly to the **for loop**, I get compilation error `"expected Integer but found &usize`. However, when I clone the usize, the for loop works.

Up on looking the documentation, the `clone()` method is expected to return `usize` as well. Is this code working because the clone method gives ownership to the for loop but the original `size` variable is passed by reference ?

```
pub enum Command {
    Uppercase,
    Trim,
    Append(usize),
}

fn some_fun(command: Command, string: String) {



 match command {
    Command::Append(size)=> {
          let mut str = string.clone();
          let s = size.clone();
          for i in 0..s {
              str.push_str("bar");
          }
                    
    
     }
  }
```

Comment: So the non-working code replaces `let s = size.clone();` and `for i in 0..s {` with just `for i in 0..size {`? And the code in your question is the working code? I'm weak/stale on Rust, but pretty sure the code above is not a [MCVE] (omitting a lot of random stuff to make it compile, and I thought you needed more than just plain unwrapped `Command::Append(size)=> {` for unpacking, at least a `let` or `match` would be needed...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a range expression, you need values, not references. The type of `size` ends up being a reference due to "match ergonomics". You don't show the expression you are matching on, but it's likely the type of your match value is `&Command`. If you add an `&` at the beginning of your pattern, i.e. `&Command::Append(size)`, the type of `size` will be `usize`, and iterating over `0..size` should work fine.

Comment: Understood. It's matching on "command". Your solution also worked. Also @Chayim's answer of using "*size" worked. 

It seems like both solutions are making sure we are iterating on values not references ?

Comment: @WowBow I wouldn't word it that way. A range expression only makes sense with values. An expression of the form `&0..&7` does represent a `Range` object, but [you can't iterate it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Step.html#implementors), and it doesn't make much sense otherwise. An expression of the form `0..&7` is simply invalid, since the type of the lower and upper bound must match. So I wouldn't say our proposed fixes makes sure you are iterating values instead of references. It makes sure the code has a meaning in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Iterating over ranges requires values, not references. However, since `usize` is `Copy`, it is better to just dereference: `for i in 0..*size`.

Comment: Yep. That worked as well. 

Also @Sven's answer of using "*&Command::Append(size)" worked. 

It seems like both solutions are making sure we are iterating on values not references ?

Comment: Yes. `*size` will dereference the `&usize` into a `usize`. `&Command::Append(size)` is a slightly weirder version of the same, it matches on a reference to `Command::Append`, which matches the rest by value, and thus matches `size` by value, also yielding a `usize`.